# docker load from tar is failing - no space left on device

Tags: docker, centos7

I am using docker over https https://x.x.198.38:2376/v1.40/images/load
And I started getting this error when running docker on Centos, this was not an issue on Ubuntu.

The image in question is 1.1gb in size.

Error Message:
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /root/.cache/node-gyp/12.21.0/include/node/v8-testing.h: **no space left on device**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bjethwan thanks for prompt response. it helped. issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue some time back.
The image might have a lot of small files and you might be falling short on disk space or inodes.

I was able to get to it only when I did "watch df -hi", it showed me that inodes were pegging up to 100 but docker cleaned up and it was back to 3%. Check this screensshot[image]

And further analysis showed that the volume attached was very small, it was just 5gb out of which 2.9 was already used by some unused images and stopped or exited containers [image]

Hence as a quick fix

```
sudo docker system prune -a
```

And this increased the inodes from 96k to 2.5m
[image]

And as a long-term fix, I increased the aws abs volume to up to 50gb as we had plans to use windows images too in the future..

HTH

Answer (score 0):

@bjethwan you caught very good command. I solved my problem.Thank you. I am using redhat. I want to add something.

watch command works 2 seconds interval at default. When i used it default, It couldnt catch the problematic inodes.

I ran watch command with 0.5 seconds. This arrested the guilty volume :)
watch -n 0.5 df -hi

After detecting the true volume you must increase it.